# Web Bluetooth not working on Chrome browser version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: web-bluetooth

I just upgraded my Chrome browser (on Ubuntu desktop) to Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit).

And now my web bluetooth HTML5 app doesn't working. It can connect to GATT server but cannot get the available services. I am using BBC micro:bit computer with this application:
https://show.io/demos/microbit/led

Could you help?

Regards,
Ferry

Comment: How are we supposed to help without seeing any of your code?

Comment: You can view source code from this site https://show.io/demos/microbit/led/. 

The program execution stuck at line 459:
return gattServer.getPrimaryService('e95dd91d-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8');

Comment: No, we won't. SO is not only a place where you'll get help, but questions and answers are supposed to be of help to future visitors as well. Which is not the case if the code at the provided URL changes or vanishes in the future. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: By the way, the program works perfectly with Chrome 61, but not 62

Comment: Here is the complete code:
[link](https://gist.github.com/ferrygun/cf481457c1a1990c8f0393b37f886def)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the doc that tracks Web Bluetooth implementation status in Chrome:

https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md

On Linux, there are some additional prerequisites:

> Linux: Requires Kernel 3.19+ and [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/) 5.41+ installed. Read [How to get Chrome Web Bluetooth working on Linux](https://acassis.wordpress.com/2016/06/28/how-to-get-chrome-web-bluetooth-working-on-linux/).
>   Note that Bluetooth daemon needs to run with experimental interfaces if BlueZ version is lower than 5.43: `sudo /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -E`